# React Native not showing undefined errors in some files

Tags: react-native, async-await

I am working on a `React Native` mobile app. For the past few days, I am experiencing a weird problem where React Native won't error out if there is some error in code for e.g. a module is not imported, or a function is not defined in some files. Mostly I have seen this error in the `App.js` file which is the main file that gets loaded in `index.ios.js`. I have a few event handlers in `componentWillMount` method of the `App.js` file and if I am using some module in that method which has not been imported, instead of showing a red screen with the `undefined` error, it just stays on the current state of the screen. I am also not able to put breakpoints in the `componentWillMount` method in Chrome. If I try to do so, it just puts the breakpoints some lines down in the code. I think it started happening when I introduced `async/await` methods in my code. The `componentWillMount` method is also an `async` method. This has greatly impacted my throughput and I am having a hard time figuring out what is wrong.

Please let me know if you have any inputs with regards to the above problems.

Comment: I have found the solution. The problem was the async function. I need to wrap all my async functions in a try catch block and console.error the errors since the function run asynchronously and somehow the errors are not routed the same way. It's amazing how just writing a question may help one find a solution since one has to gather all the information regarding the problem in one place which can help connect the dots and solve the problem.

Comment: I still have the problem where I am not able to set breakpoints at certain lines in the JS code in Chrome. Please let me know what may be causing it. I have confirmed that those lines of code are reachable by printing console.logs.